# How to make Sublime Text 2 spell check comments only?

Tags: sublime-text-2, spell-check

The built-in spell check feature seems to be running over the whole code, underlining lots of text that is supposed to be that way i.e. the code itself.

Any way to limit it to just comments (`//`)?

Comment: There's this, but I've no time to dig into it: `"spelling_selector": "markup.raw, source string.quoted - punctuation - meta.preprocessor.c.include, source comment - source comment.block.preprocessor, -(source, constant, keyword, storage, support, variable, markup.underline.link, meta.tag)",`

Comment: I don'tk know about Sublime 2 but Sublime 3 does it out of the box. The settings "spelling_selector", allow to control which scopes are checked.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no direct way of limiting the spell checking parser to only comments in Sublime Text 2 (but this is simple to do in Sublime Text 3). These programs are not written to differentiate text document and some code syntax. So most of the code syntax looks like spelling errors. The best solution is to toggle spell-check with <kbd>F6</kbd> and right-click on the spelling error to change the spelling. Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to move to next misspelling and change it.

Comment: How can this be done in ST3?

Comment: @SLesslyTall There is a [**_`spelling_selector`_**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/settings.html?highlight=spelling_selector) parameter in settings for sublime text 3. There you can adjust scope of spellcheck. It is not perfect so you might still prefer to toggle `F6`to avoid distraction from red lines.